# Closed form solution for a problem on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k$ be a collection of non-empty mutually disjoint sets. Assume $A = \cup_{i=1}^k A_i$ and $|A_i| = n_i$. Let $P_m(A)$ be the set of all $m$ elements subsets of $A$. For $S \in P_m(A)$, define $t_i = |A_i \cap S|$ and $S_r = \{ 1 \le i \le k: t_i > 0\}$  .

How to simplify the following expression so that the answer will be a more explicit function of possibly binomial coefficients and other similar well-known combinatorial quantities?

$$\sum\limits_{S \in P_m(A)} \sum\limits_{i \in S_r}(t_i -1).$$

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried? For example, what if you fix $|S_r|=k$. Also, what is the $r$ in $S_r$?

Comment: In $S_r$, r is just to mean the set of representatives: one element of s for each $A_i$ it intersects.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_i = \{S \in P_m(A) : t_i > 0\}$. Then
$$\sum_{i \in S_r} (t_i - 1) = m - |S_r|, \quad \sum_{S \in P_m(A)} |S_r| = \sum_{1\le i\le k} |S_i|,$$
$$|S_i| = |P_m(A) \setminus P_m(A \setminus A_i)| = \binom{|A|}{m} - \binom{|A|-|A_i|}{m},$$
and so
$$\sum_{S \in P_m(A)}\sum_{i \in S_r} (t_i - 1) = (m-k) \binom{|A|}{m} + \sum_{1\le i\le k} \binom{|A|-n_i}{m}.$$